# (Collatz) Modulo 18 Partitions of Collatz 3n+1 Trajectories

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

I have examined partial Collatz 3n+1 trajectories going from one odd integer to the next.   These lead to an infinite number of repeated patterns where the "next" odd integer is congruent to one of only six patterns:  {5, 11, 17, 1, 7 or 3} mod 18.   As was pointed out by Mirko in an earlier comment, these are the only possible Collatz results for mod 18, so it may seem trivial, but what I found interesting was a rotation pattern in the transformations, which I will try to illustrate rather than formally define.

The patterns resulting in {5, 11, 17} (mod 18) are shown in the table below; the cycle repeats every third even level, so $A_0$ and $A_6$ reach {5, 11, 17} from the same starting points {3,1,5} (mod 6).

$$ \begin{array} {|c|cc|cc|cc|cc|}
\hline 
SET & INPUT & MOD & TRANSFORM & MOD & INPUT MOD 6 & TRANSFORM MOD 6 \\
\hline
\cdots & 3 & 12 & 5 & 18 & 3 & 5 \\
A_0 & 7 & 12 & 11 & 18 & 1 & 5 \\
\cdots & 11 & 12 & 17 & 18 & 5 & 5 \\
\hline
\cdots & 13 & 48 & 5 & 18 & 1 & 5 \\
A_2 & 29 &48 &11 & 18 &5 & 5 \\
\cdots & 45 & 48 & 17 & 18 &3 & 5 \\
\hline
\cdots & 53 & 192 &5 & 18 & 5 & 5 \\
A_4 & 117 &192 & 11 & 18 &3 &5 \\
\cdots & 181 & 192& 17 &18 &1 &5 \\
\hline
\cdots & 213 & 768 & 5 & 18 &3 & 5 \\
A_6 & 469 &768 & 11 & 18 & 1 & 5 \\
\cdots &725 & 768 & 17 & 18 & 5 & 5 \\
\hline 
\end{array}
$$

Similarly, the patterns resulting in {1, 7, 13} (mod 18) are shown in the table below; the cycle repeats every third odd level, so $A_1$ and $A_7$ reach {1, 7, 13} from the same starting points {1,3,5} (mod 6).

$$ \begin{array} {|c|cc|cc|cc|cc|}
\hline 
SET & INPUT & MOD & TRANSFORM & MOD & INPUT MOD 6 & TRANSFORM MOD 6 \\
\hline
\cdots & 1 & 24 & 1 & 18 & 1 & 1 \\
A_1 & 9 & 24 & 7 & 18 & 3 & 1 \\
\cdots & 17 & 24 & 13 & 18 & 5 & 1 \\
\hline
\cdots & 5 & 96 & 1 & 18 & 5 & 1 \\
A_3 & 37 & 96 & 7 & 18 & 1 & 1 \\
\cdots & 69 & 96 & 13 & 18 & 3 & 1 \\
\hline
\cdots & 21 & 384 & 1 & 18 & 3 & 1 \\
A_5 & 149 & 384 & 7 & 18 & 5 & 1 \\
\cdots & 277 & 384 & 13 & 18 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\cdots & 85 &1536 & 1 & 18 & 1 & 1 \\
A_7 & 597 & 1536 & 7 & 18 & 3 & 1 \\
\cdots & 1109 & 1536 & 13 & 18 & 5 & 1 \\
\hline 
\end{array}
$$

QUESTION:  Are these observed patterns useful in attacking the Collatz 3N+1 problem?

OBSERVATIONS:

(1) The path among the first members of each partition is given by:
$$7 => 11 => 17 => 13 => 5 => 1$$

(2) There is a one-step path to each of them from $\left(3\;mod\;6
\right)$
$$3=>5\;;9=>7\;;21=>1\;;45=>17\;;69=>13\;;117=>11$$

(3) Applying the Collatz transformations a second time to the six partitions shows that the Collatz transformations map these partitions among themselves.  A portion of this mapping is show below.
$$ 
\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
FROM & SECOND & EQUIVALENT & FROM \\
PARTITION & TRANSFORM & TRANSFORM & SET \\
\hline
11 mod 18 & 11 mod 36 => 17 mod 54 & 11 mod 12 => 17 mod 18 & A_{0} \\
5 mod 18 & 23 mod 36 => 35 mod 54 & 11 mod 12 => 17 mod 18 &  A_{0} \\
17 mod 18 & 35 mod 36 => 53 mod 54 & 11 mod 12 => 17 mod 18 &  A_{0} \\
\hline
7 mod 18 & 7 mod 36 => 11 mod 54 & 7 mod 12 => 11 mod 18 & A_{0} \\ 
1 mod 18 & 19 mod 36 => 29 mod 54 & 7 mod 12 => 11 mod 18 & A_{0} \\
13 mod 18 & 31 mod 36 => 47 mod 54 & 7 mod 12 => 11 mod 18 & A_{0} \\
\hline
1 mod 18 & 1 mod 72 => 1 mod 54 & 1 mod 24 => 1 mod 18 &  A_{1} \\
7 mod 18 & 25 mod 72 => 19 mod 54 & 1 mod 24 => 1 mod 18 &  A_{1} \\
13 mod 18 & 49 mod 72 => 37 mod 54 & 1 mod 24 => 1 mod 18 &  A_{1} \\
\hline
17 mod 18 & 17 mod 72 => 13 mod 54 & 17 mod 24 => 13 mod 18 & A_{1} \\
5 mod 18 & 41 mod 72 => 31 mod 54 & 17 mod 24 => 13 mod 18 & A_{1} \\
11 mod 18 & 65 mod 72 => 49 mod 54 & 17 mod 24 => 13 mod 18 & A_{1} \\
\hline
11 mod 18 & 29 mod 144 => 11 mod 54 & 29 mod 48 => 11 mod 18 &  A_{2} \\
5 mod 18 & 77 mod 144 => 29 mod 54 & 29 mod 48 => 11 mod 18 &  A_{2} \\
17 mod 18 & 125 mod 144 => 47 mod 54 & 29 mod 48 => 11 mod 18 &  A_{2} \\
\hline
13 mod 18 & 13 mod 144 => 13 mod 54 & 13 mod 48 => 5 mod 18 & A_{2} \\
7 mod 18 & 61 mod 144 => 31 mod 54 & 13 mod 48 => 5 mod 18 & A_{2} \\
1 mod 18 & 109 mod 144 => 49 mod 54 & 13 mod 48 => 5 mod 18 & A_{2} \\
\hline
5 mod 18 & 5 mod 288 => 1 mod 54 & 5 mod 96 =>1 mod 18 &  A_{3} \\
11 mod 18 & 101 mod 288 => 19 mod 54 & 5 mod 96 =>1 mod 18 &  A_{3} \\
17 mod 18 & 197 mod 288 => 37 mod 54 & 5 mod 96 =>1 mod 18 &  A_{3} \\
\hline
1 mod 18 & 37 mod 288 => 7 mod 54 & 37 mod 96 => 7 mod 18 & A_{3} \\
7 mod 18 & 133 mod 288 => 25 mod 54 & 37 mod 96 => 7 mod 18 & A_{3} \\
13 mod 18 & 229 mod 288 => 43 mod 54 & 37 mod 96 => 7 mod 18 & A_{3} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

(4) So, after the first Collatz iteration removes multiples of three, the transformations in remaining iterations all work from the same set of six modulo 18 partitions and until studied further, this lends no particular insight into whether a particular sequence will cycle, diverge or revert to 1.

(5) The second iteration, sorted by source partition ...

$$ 
\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
FROM & SECOND & SUBSET \; OF & FROM \\
PARTITION & TRANSFORM & TRANSFORM & SET \\
\hline
1 mod 18 & 19 mod 36 => 29 mod 54 & 7 mod 12 => 11 mod 18 & A_{0} \\
1 mod 18 & 1 mod 72 => 1 mod 54 & 1 mod 24 => 1 mod 18 &  A_{1} \\
1 mod 18 & 109 mod 144 => 49 mod 54 & 13 mod 48 => 5 mod 18 & A_{2} \\
1 mod 18 & 37 mod 288 => 7 mod 54 & 37 mod 96 => 7 mod 18 & A_{3} \\
1 mod 18 & 181 mod 576 => 17 mod 54 & 181 mod 192 => 17 mod 18 & A_{4} \\
1 mod 18 & 1045 mod 1152 => 49 mod 54 & 277 mod 384 => 13 mod 18 & A_{5} \\
\hline
5 mod 18 & 23 mod 36 => 35 mod 54 & 11 mod 12 => 17 mod 18 &  A_{0} \\
5 mod 18 & 41 mod 72 => 31 mod 54 & 17 mod 24 => 13 mod 18 & A_{1} \\
5 mod 18 & 77 mod 144 => 29 mod 54 & 29 mod 48 => 11 mod 18 &  A_{2} \\
5 mod 18 & 5 mod 288 => 1 mod 54 & 5 mod 96 =>1 mod 18 &  A_{3} \\
5 mod 18 & 437 mod 576 => 41 mod 54 & 53 mod 192 => 5 mod 18 & A_{4} \\
5 mod 18 & 149 mod 1152 => 7 mod 54 & 149 mod 384 = > 7 mod 18 & A_{5} \\
\hline
7 mod 18 & 7 mod 36 => 11 mod 54 & 7 mod 12 => 11 mod 18 & A_{0} \\ 
7 mod 18 & 25 mod 72 => 19 mod 54 & 1 mod 24 => 1 mod 18 &  A_{1} \\
7 mod 18 & 61 mod 144 => 31 mod 54 & 13 mod 48 => 5 mod 18 & A_{2} \\
7 mod 18 & 133 mod 288 => 25 mod 54 & 37 mod 96 => 7 mod 18 & A_{3} \\
7 mod 18 & 565 mod 576 => 53 mod 54 & 181 mod 192 => 17 mod 18 & A_{4} \\
7 mod 18 & 277 mod 1152 => 13 mod 54 & 277 mod 384 => 13 mod 18 & A_{5} \\
\hline
11 mod 18 & 11 mod 36 => 17 mod 54 & 11 mod 12 => 17 mod 18 & A_{0} \\
11 mod 18 & 65 mod 72 => 49 mod 54 & 17 mod 24 => 13 mod 18 & A_{1} \\
11 mod 18 & 29 mod 144 => 11 mod 54 & 29 mod 48 => 11 mod 18 &  A_{2} \\
11 mod 18 & 101 mod 288 => 19 mod 54 & 5 mod 96 =>1 mod 18 &  A_{3} \\
11 mod 18 & 245 mod 576 => 23 mod 54 & 53 mod 192 => 17 mod 18 & A_{4} \\
11 mod 18 & 533 mod 1152 => 25 mod 54 & 149 mod 384 = > 7 mod 18 & A_{5} \\
\hline
13 mod 18 & 31 mod 36 => 47 mod 54 & 7 mod 12 => 11 mod 18 & A_{0} \\
13 mod 18 & 49 mod 72 => 37 mod 54 & 1 mod 24 => 1 mod 18 &  A_{1} \\
13 mod 18 & 13 mod 144 => 5 mod 54 & 13 mod 48 => 5 mod 18 & A_{2} \\
13 mod 18 & 229 mod 288 => 43 mod 54 & 37 mod 96 => 7 mod 18 & A_{3} \\
13 mod 18 & 373 mod 576 => 35 mod 54 & 181 mod 192 => 17 mod 18 & A_{4} \\
13 mod 18 & 661 mod 1152 => 31 mod 54 & 277 mod 384 => 13 mod 18 & A_{5} \\
\hline
17 mod 18 & 35 mod 36 => 53 mod 54 & 11 mod 12 => 17 mod 18 &  A_{0} \\
17 mod 18 & 17 mod 72 => 13 mod 54 & 17 mod 24 => 13 mod 18 & A_{1} \\
17 mod 18 & 125 mod 144 => 47 mod 54 & 29 mod 48 => 11 mod 18 &  A_{2} \\
17 mod 18 & 197 mod 288 => 37 mod 54 & 5 mod 96 =>1 mod 18 &  A_{3} \\
17 mod 18 & 53 mod 576 => 17 mod 54 & 53 mod 192 => 17 mod 18 & A_{4} \\
17 mod 18 & 917 mod 1152 => 43 mod 54 & 149 mod 384 = > 7 mod 18 & A_{5} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Lots of people have tried lots of ideas, and found lots of patterns.  The hard part is the proof.

Comment: The idea is new to me but after a bit of inspection I do not find it interesting. Of all the remainders $\mod 18$, you must exclude even numbers (since **odd$\mod 18=$ odd**), and you also must exclude numbers divisible by $3$, since $3n+1$ is not divisible by $3$. What is left is the possible remainders $1,5,7,11,13,17,$ no way to get a different number as a remainder. I do not know what you are saying with "*I have formulae for these patterns in terms of the number of members in the partial trajectory*" can't comment without seeing details.Perhaps you could come up with something interesting

Comment: Added the formulae.   The fact that these patterns keep showing up at higher and higher levels of k is what interests me.

Comment: In http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121264/collatz-conjecture-largest-number-in-sequence-with-starting-number-n/1123151#1123151 I show that problem in a nice table for only one step (mod 6). I've tried this also for two steps (separating classed according to mod 18) and also for three steps (mod 54). Unfortunately I didn't find any interesting pattern which would have allowed to conclude something more advanced. So I personally do not have any more hope in this concept. But well, always a widened horizont and insight might sometimes result in new ideas - so...

Comment: Perhaps a bit better representation of the $\small \pmod 6 $ - table: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137364/thoughts-on-the-collatz-conjecture-integers-added-to-powers-of-2/808928#808928

Comment: Thanks Gottfried, I was fairly certain that someone else would have seen this pattern, it was very easy to see on a spreadsheet;  I also tried to work with the modulo 18 and modulo 54 patterns and realize that is yet another way to approach infinity, but I am hoping the formulae might make it possible to attempt a mathematical induction proof.

Comment: Perhaps this old and very amateurish discussion of mine is interesting for you http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz061102.pdf Page 6 to 7 there is a small discussion of this (mod 18)- idea. I think it is a nice collection of ideas, which should also be straightened in a second writing...

Comment: Thanks again Gottfried.    Your chart is similar to the path I was on.   I'm beginning to think the Collatz problem exists to seduce us into getting very familiar with the nature of the odd positive integers.

Comment: @Mirko  I see now that my "discovery" was trivial, thanks for pointing it out.   What I'm really doing is trying to organize my thoughts around how to attack the Collatz problem, which is more about how to partition the odd integers.

Comment: My next thought is to look at how specific sequences move among the six partitions.

Comment: I'm sorry this question isn't receiving attention on MSE, but editing a post dozens of times tends to get old quickly.

Comment: I really don't think this question is a good fit for the platform - "Are these observed patterns useful in attacking the Collatz problem?" is really only answerable if we have a proof of the Collatz problem in hand and it's *very* broad - which is especially troublesome given that this is a soft question. As it stands, I can't imagine what an answer would look like, and the author's edits aren't moving in the right direction for this.

Comment: Stop the incessant editing. Right away. It irritates other users because it moves their questions off the front page. If you foresee the need to edit a post a lot use [the  sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4666/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  I'm very sorry I haven't been on the site that long and had no idea that incremental effort to capture my ideas would be systemically annoying.    Seems like it should be simple to turn on a "draft mode" so you can see your edits without broadcasting them, but I can see from the "sandbox" effort that it takes a crazy workaround to make it happen.    I just need to correct an error an then I'll leave it alone until I have further insight.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Okay I'm done with this question

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thanks for your help earlier, see my answer for where this line of thinking took me (finally)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I can finally see something of interest (to me) in this exercise.   The formula for the transformation of an odd integer to the next odd integer is related to the partition in which that next odd integer resides.   If $n_0$ represents any odd integer which starts a sequence representing the odd numbers only in a Collatz 3n+1 sequence,  the formula for $n_1$ is given by.

$$ n_1 = (3n_0 + 1) / {\left(2^k\right)} $$ 
$$ \;for\; some\; k \in N $$ 
$$ where \; k \cong \left(1\;mod\;2\right) \equiv n_1 \cong \left(5\;mod\;6\right) $$ 
$$ and \; where \; k \cong \left(0\;mod\;2\right) \equiv n_1 \cong \left(1\;mod\;6\right). $$

The significance is this that 
$$ \left(n_1 \gt n_0 \iff k=1\right) \implies \left(n_1 \gt n_0 \implies n_1 \cong \left(5 \; mod \; 6\right) \right) $$

So we can focus on (5 mod 6) to look for divergence behavior.

Answer (score 0):

5 mod 6 is the same as -1 mod 6.
A number satisfying that would be a number of the form (2)(3)z-1 where z is a (nonnegative) integer. 
Such a number is the image by the transformation T(x) = (3x+1)/2 
of the number x = (2)(2)z-1.

Consider "runs" of consecutive odd iterates of T. 
If you have more factors 3 in z, you can go "back" (and down) further in the same "run" by replacing (some of) these 3's by 2's. 
If you have more factors 2 in z, you can go "forward" (and up) further in the same "run" by replacing (some of) these 2's by 3's.

Any odd x can be written x = (2^n)u-1 with u odd. Then if T is iterated starting from x, the (n-1)-th iteration will give the last consecutive odd number in the sequence, and that will be of the form 1+4k. (The n-th iteration will give an even number.) You could call this sequence of n odd values (that includes x) a "run" starting from x. 
If u has some factors 3, replacing those by 2's one by one will produce "precedents" to x, until there are no more factors 3. The last (and smallest) number obtained this way starts the maximal run that contains x. That maximal run is uniquely identified by its last and highest point 1+4k, or its "label" k.

Eventually, each odd (nonnegative) integer can be put in exactly one maximal (but finite) "run". Any two such maximal runs are either the same or disjoint. 
If they are disjoint, they might "communicate" (in one or more "jump" step), or not. (This is as far as I got.)

Comment: Please [format](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) your answer to make it easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

The patterns resulting in $\{1, 7, 13\} \pmod {18}$ can be explained if you view these results in mod $9$. All odd $n$ under function $3n+1$ iterate to $1$, $7$, or $4 \pmod 9$. I believe this pattern is non-trivial.

Comment: I haven't been on site for a few years. Has this answer been deleted? If so why.